# Webpack ignora el archivo webpack.config.js

Tags: nodejs, npm, webpack

Estoy siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-4-tutorial/) para aprender sobre Webpack... El tema es que configuré el archivo de la siguiente manera:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/entry",
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Y tengo mi `package.json` de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  "name": "pruebaWebpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0"
  }
}
```

Pero al parecer está ignorando el archivo de configuración porque cuando corro `npm run build` va a buscar a los archivos por defecto (entry = ./src y output = ./dist) y no reconoce el atributo `mode`:

> pruebaWebpack@1.0.0 build /opt/lampp/htdocs/pruebaWebpack
>
> webpack
>
> Hash: 4a9c3de0f194dd38ac70 Version: webpack 4.4.1
>
> Time: 234ms
>
> Built at: 2018-4-1 15:53:00   Asset       Size  Chunks
>   Chunk
>
> Names main.js  564 bytes       0  [emitted]  main Entrypoint main =
>   main.js    [0] ./src/index.js 19 bytes {0} [built]
>
> WARNING in configuration The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack
>   will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to
>   'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
>   You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn
>   more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

Comment: El error está en tu package.json

Comment: Podrías decirme cuál es el error por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví como indiqué en [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54461185/7058363) a la misma pregunta en Stack Overflow inglés: al parecer había un espacio en blanco en el nombre del archivo ( `webpack.config.js`) que no era perceptible desde VSCode. Cuando renombré el archivo borrando ese espacio en blanco todo funcionó correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces

```
npm run build
```

se ejecuta la linea build dentro de script en tu **`package.json`**.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
  },
```

segun la [documentacion de Webpack](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-4-tutorial/), debes cambiar tu **`package.json`** un poco

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --mode development",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
  "qa": "webpack --mode qa"
}
```

si quieres ejecutar el comando modo develop debes ejecutar:

```
npm run dev
```

> La forma que usa node/npm con distintos frameworks se basa en el **`package.json`** que simplemente es disminuir el comando para que sea mas facil aprender y evitar los parametros que aveces son engorrosos aprenderlos; en tu ejemplo puedes correr **`npm run test`** y observaras `"Error: no test specified"`

Comment: Lo he hecho, el tema es que no reconoce los parametros entry y output del webpack.config.js. Y no solo eso, tampoco los parametros de loader. Por lo que puedo deducir que simplemente ignora el archivo. Así que sigo en la misma, puedo poner el `mode` en el script, pero hay muchisimos parametros dentro del webpack.config que sigo perdiendo

Comment: ahora si lo vi la entrada es un archivo.js , en el ejemplo que colocastes lo tienes   "dev": "webpack --mode development ./foo/src/js/index.js --output ./foo/main.js",
  "build": "webpack --mode production ./foo/src/js/index.js --output ./foo/main.js"

Comment: Aún cuando no seteo el entry y el output sigue sin reconocer atributos como el loader y el mode. Voy a probar clonando un repositorio demo de Webpack con React a ver si me anda. Muchisimas gracias por la molestia, en cuanto tenga noticias completo la pregunta

Comment: cuando agregas babel tienes que agregar el .babelrc posiblemente sea eso no ha podido transpilar el codigo, igual no tengo la respuesta exacta

Comment: Ya tengo seteado el .babelrc también, con los presets predefinidos. La verdad que no sé que está pasando, pero gracias por la ayuda!